# how to change the order of categorical values on X-axis when using seaborn.FacetGrid?

Tags: python, seaborn, axis-labels, facet-grid

I have following code:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(correct_data, hue="congruency", col="PP", row="cue", height=4, ylim=(.4, .9))
g.map(sns.pointplot, "pattern", "RT")
```

This allows me to create a line plot per participant (PP) and cue (cue) showing separate lines for each level of congruency. Each line shows the relationship between pattern (X-axis) and reaction time (RT on the Y-axis). I would like the reverse the order of the categorical values on the X-axis, how can I do this?
The "pattern"-variable has two levels, but I like to reverse the default order in which it is displayed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the [`order=` parameter](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html?highlight=pointplot#seaborn.pointplot) (as well as `hue_order=`) to `sns.pointplot()` inside the call to `g.map()` to choose the order of the categorical variable

```
att = sns.load_dataset("attention")
g = sns.FacetGrid(att, col="subject", col_wrap=5, height=1.5)
g = g.map(sns.pointplot, "solutions", "score", order=[3,1,2])
```

[image]